# How to integrate sumoselect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sumoselect.js

My js skills are very low, so sorry for this question. I need a multiselect to filter my boxes. The [sumoselect](http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) plugin looks smart and I am able to run it, but I don´t know how to integrate it to my boxes. For example, if I select "Volvo & Mercedes" at my multiselect, I want that the other boxes fade out. At deselection all boxes are shown.

That´s my current status:

```
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.select').on('change', function(e) {
        console.log($(this).val()) // value
    }).SumoSelect({})

    $('#submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var v = $('#uq').val();
        alert(v);
    });
});
```

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvyuam80/)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify the `box`  html a bit to include the values of the `<select>`

```
 <span class="box" data-select_match="bmw">BMW</span>
```

Then you can filter the boxes based on the added attribute:

```
var $boxes = $('.box');
$('.select').on('change', function(e) {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if(!selected ){
        $boxes.show()
    }else{
        $boxes.hide().filter(function(){ // hide boxes then filter what gets shown
            var select_match = $(this).data('select_match');
            return selected.indexOf(select_match) > -1;
        }).show();
    }       
}).SumoSelect({})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pvyuam80/1/)**</kbd>